# Connect Zebra RW420 Printer to smart device

Tags: vb.net, zebra-printers, smart-device

I am currently researching on VB.net on how to connect Zebra RW420 Printer to smart device via Bluetooth, i surfed the internet and found nothing useful for me, will it need SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth connection can be accomplished either by using the Bluetooth utility to pair with the printer and assign that connection a comm port. Your VB program will then open that comm port, write the data to be sent to the printer to that comm port, and then close it. The other way to communicate via Bluetooth is to make the connection by passing the printer's Bluetooth address. You will probably need a third party or the smart device manufacturer's SDK or tool to be able to communicate with the printer using the Bluetooth address. The last option, and in opinion the best option, is to use the [Zebra SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink.html). It lets you connect to the printer either through comm port connection or by the Bluetooth address, whichever fits your solution better; You will find VB examples in the Zebra SDK documentation.